# Flutter : Showing nested data received from serve : Edited #3

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart

I have an app receive nested data from server in the page i print the data's and it is printed successfully :

class page :

```
  final DateTime mDate;
  final List<Games> games;

class DatedMatchs {
  DatedMatchs(
    this.mDate,
    this.games,
  );
}
class Games {
  Games(
    this.id,this.sId,this.wId,this.leagueName,this.homeTeam,this.awayTeam,this.homeGoals,this.awayGoals,this.mHour,this.homeEx,this.awayEx,
  );
  final String id;
  final String sId;
  final String wId;
  final String leagueName;
  final String homeTeam;
  final String awayTeam;
  final String homeGoals;
  final String awayGoals;
  final String mHour;
  final String homeEx;
  final String awayEx;
}
```

page i want to show data:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../models/dated_matchs.dart';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List matchs = [];
    Future<List> getmatchs() async {
      var url =
          'xxx/api/controller/matchs/dated_matchs.php?s_id=1';
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
    }
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getmatchs(),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          return Container();
        });
  }
}
```

Now i don't know how to add received data to a list then show it on list-view

### I used this way inside future function but there is something wrong :

```
Future<List> getmatchs() async {
  var url =
      'xxx/api/controller/matchs/dated_matchs.php?s_id=1';
  var response = await http.get(url);
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  for (var x in data) {
    for (var y in x['games']) {
      cont1.add(TextEditingController());
      cont2.add(TextEditingController());
      Games newmatch = Games(
          y['id'],
          y['s_id'],
          y['w_id'],
          y['league_name'],
          y['home_team'],
          y['away_team'],
          y['home_goals'],
          y['away_goals'],
          y['m_hour'],
          y['home_ex'],
          y['away_ex']);
      matchs.add(newmatch);
    }
    DatedMatchs newdated = DatedMatchs(x['m_date'], x['matchs']);
    datedmatchs.add(newdated);
  }
  return datedmatchs;
}
```

no thing print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it and below the future method which get me list of data correctly :

```
    List<Games> games = [];                       // I added type of List
    List<DatedMatchs> datedmatchs = [];       // I added type of List
    Future<List> getmatchs() async {
      var url =
          'xxx/api/controller/matchs/dated_matchs.php?s_id=1';
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var data = await jsonDecode(response.body);
      for (var x in data) {
        for (var y in x['games']) {
          cont1.add(TextEditingController());
          cont2.add(TextEditingController());
          Games newmatch = Games(
              y['id'],
              y['s_id'],
              y['w_id'],
              y['league_name'],
              y['home_team'],
              y['away_team'],
              y['home_goals'],
              y['away_goals'],
              y['m_hour'],
              y['home_ex'],
              x['away_ex']);
          games.add(newmatch);
        }
        DatedMatchs newdated = DatedMatchs(x['m_date'], games); // add name of list
        datedmatchs.add(newdated);
      }
      return datedmatchs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your data is coming back as a Map, rather than a List.  You'll need to debug and see which data is a Map, then you can print it from the Map.

Also, I wouldn't call an api in your UI.  It's best to use a state management library, such as Bloc, Provider, or RxDart.

Comment: thanks alot ,I changed my way to get data ,I will edit my question if you can help me with many thanks

Comment: Your data is going to show as a Map<String, dynamic>. The way you access a map is by iterating through the keys.

Comment: Does it print the correct data in the method?  print(data)

Comment: Your games model uses named parameters, but you're not naming them when you instantiate the model in your getmatchs() method.  Are you getting compilation errors?

Comment: I changed named parameters

Comment: I think my problem is in this line :DatedMatchs newdated = DatedMatchs(x['m_date'], x['matchs']); 
the list matchs didn't add to new list

Comment: You should post an answer and mark it, so others can search for it if they have any similar problems.